# How to add Oracle driver in the DBeaver on a Macbook M3

Tags: oracle, jdbc, dbeaver

I downloaded the DBeaver (23.2.0) to connect to my Oracle database. It was working on my previous Macbook (M1). I put in all the credentials and tried connecting, but I keep getting errors like

> dbviewer oracle database throws Network unavailable
> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:PKIX path building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target

I tried some solutions from the internet, but nothing seemed to work. I ended up deleting Oracle driver from my DBeaver driver manager and now I cannot find 'Oracle' when I am trying to find database connections to connect to (Oracle does not appear in the options)

I have reinstalled the DBeaver a couple of times but still I don't see Oracle in my DBeaver. My question is if I uninstalled the driver, they should be reinstalled when I download DBeaver again, but it does not happen.

I have tried deleting and reinstalling dbeaver even different versions but Oracle driver is not there. I want the option back to connect with the Oracle database.

Comment: You probably need to delete DBeaver user settings, somewhere in your user directory.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this issue by deleting a directory called `DBeaverData` in my directory under my username/Library. After deleting the directory, I re-installed DBeaver and it appeared with Oracle connection option. Also, this time around, when I tried connecting with the Oracle DB, it asked some upgrades to the driver and finally succeeded.